# How to create a derived column in a CSV file using linux/python?

Tags: python, linux, csv, derived-column

I have a CSV(sample) file with the below columns

```
PC_name,Time,Plant,Section,PC_value
35901052,2017-08-01 05:50,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000
35901052,2017-08-01 05:51,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000
35901052,2017-08-01 05:56,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000
35901052,2017-08-01 06:01,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000
35901052,2017-08-01 06:06,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000
```

And I want a new column "**New**" based on the "**Time**" column as explained below

If my timestamp range between **6pm(18:00)** to **6am(06:00)** then the value should be "**Night**" else "**Day**"

Sample output:

```
PC_name,Time,Plant,Section,PC_value,New
35901052,2017-08-01 05:50,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000,Night
35901052,2017-08-01 05:51,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000,Night
35901052,2017-08-01 05:56,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000,Night
35901052,2017-08-01 06:01,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000,Day
35901052,2017-08-01 06:06,MIYAKONOJO,MIYAKONOJO_05,0.000,Day
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use pandas and numpy, do as below using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [pandas.Series.dt.hour](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)

```
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv',parse_dates=['Time'])
df['New'] = np.where((df.Time.dt.hour > 5) & (df.Time.dt.hour <18),'Day','Night')

df>>
    PC_name                Time       Plant        Section  PC_value    New
0  35901052 2017-08-01 05:50:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
1  35901052 2017-08-01 05:51:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
2  35901052 2017-08-01 05:56:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
3  35901052 2017-08-01 06:01:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0    Day
4  35901052 2017-08-01 06:06:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0    Day

df.to_csv('New_filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your series to Datetime and extract the hour. Then map it to values

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df["New"] = df["Time"].dt.hour.map({hour: "Night" if 18 < hour or hour < 6 else "Day" for hour in range(23)})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    PC_name                Time       Plant        Section  PC_value    New
0  35901052 2017-08-01 05:50:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
1  35901052 2017-08-01 05:51:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
2  35901052 2017-08-01 05:56:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0  Night
3  35901052 2017-08-01 06:01:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0    Day
4  35901052 2017-08-01 06:06:00  MIYAKONOJO  MIYAKONOJO_05       0.0    Day
```